# How to upload images to rails api app with react and carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to upload images to a rails 5 api app with carrierwave and react but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here're some parts of the app.

**migration**

```
class AddImagesToTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :topics, :images, :json
  end
end
```

**topic model**

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :images, ImageUploader
  ...
end
```

**topics controller**

```
def topic_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :options, :subject, :body, {images: []})
end
```

**submitted form logs**

```
@topic = @board.topics.new(topic_params)

p "-----------"
p params[:topic][:images]
p @topic
p "-----------"
```

gives the following:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :images
"-----------"
<ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>{}} permitted: false>
#<Topic id: nil, board_id: 5, body: "dsf", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: "", options: "", subject: "", images: nil>
"-----------"
```

**form**

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      topic: {
        name: "",
        options: "",
        subject: "",
        body: "",
        images: null
      }
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleImagesSelect = this.handleImagesSelect.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.add_topic(this.props.perm, this.state);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ topic: { ...this.state.topic, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } });
  }

  handleImagesSelect(e) {
    this.setState({ topic: { ...this.state.topic, images: e.target.files } });
    console.log(e.target.files);
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, options, subject, body, images } = this.state.topic
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="form_wrapper">
          <form id="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit } encType="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                ....
                <tr>
                  <td>body</td>
                  <td>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" rows="10" cols="50"
                    value={body}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>file</td>
                  <td>
                    <input name="images" type="file" id="images" multiple="true"
                    onChange={this.handleImagesSelect}/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**add topic action**

```
export function add_topic(perm, topic) {
  return dispatch => {

    axios.post(api + perm + "/topics/", topic)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: ADD_TOPIC, payload: res.data })
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to send image info in formdata. like `fd = new FormData(); fd.append('images',e.target.files)`

Comment: i think you need to set `FormData` in `handleSubmit` function and append images there.  like `fd.append('images', this.state.images)`

Comment: is there a way to upload an image without using `FormData`?

Comment: I never finished this so to speak "project" and just dumped it. You can check it here though https://github.com/kirqe/b. Send pr's if interested :)